# swift 3 tableview.reloadData crashes the app

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8

i have got a table view which gets data from core data.
this works fine, but if i send the command tbl.reloadData it will chrashes my app.

this is my code for get data and reload it:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tbl: NSTableView!
  func requestData() {

        let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Test")

        do {
            data = try context.fetch(request) as! [Data]

        } catch { }

        print(data)

        tbl.reloadData()

    }
```

print(data) shows me successfully all my data of core data.
but on the line "tbl.reloadData()" the app will crash with this error:

```
    fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-05-03 14:24:47.750618+0200 Programm[36302:1990301] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: tbl outlet is correctly bound to its View in Interface Builder?

Comment: yes it is correctly

Comment: ALL OK ! i dont now why, but i delete the connection of tableview and controller and connect it again - now it works ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing that can be nil after that print statement is tbl object. Make sure:

- you have connected the IBOutlet properly.
- removed old connections from storyboard. The ones you created previously and now renamed the variable name or deleted the variable entirely.

Also for some reason your code has `NSTableView` make sure you are looking for that and not the one column style `UITableView`.